# Combining reasoners in OWL API for OWL DL + SQWRL support

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api, swrl

I need to calculate some SQWRL rules on a OWL 2 DL ontology.

The problem is:

- Current OWL 2 DL reasoners only support SWRL builtins
- The only SQWRL SWRLAPI engine is drools-swrlapi wich is OWL 2 RL and will not be able to process my DL ontology

I consider two possible solutions:

1. Use OWLAPI directly in Java to execute SQWRL on top of OWL 2 DL reasoner (like Pellet)
2. Somehow use both reasoners (Pellet and Drools-SWRLAPI) and avoid static java code

so my question is: is it possible to combine two reasoners so that they will not conflict?

Like

1. pre-compute inferences with DL reasoner
2. run the resulting ontology on Drools-SWRLAPI to execute SQWRL
3. put that back to DL reasoner and validate/compute more inferences
4. loop

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable if the `OWLReasoner` is created as non-buffering and Drools-SWRLAPI materializes all inferred triples in the input ontology. This might not be the case, so it might be necessary to take steps to materialize these inferences.

I'm not familiar with the SWRL API and the Drools rule engine, so I cannot say whether this is doable or easy; I'd probably start by taking one of the Open Source reasoners that support SWRL and try to replace their SWRL support with the Drools code - this has the advantage of ensuring that the algorithm the reasoners use to ensure correctness and completeness is applied (looping between the two reasoning approaches should be a good approximation, but there might be corner cases missed, as well as lost optimizations.

The reverse approach, i.e., materializing OWL2DL inferences and applying SWRL rules afterwards, has the weakness of having to choose which inferences to materialize; class expressions in the taxonomy won't travel easily across the `OWLReasoner` interface, and the process might be very computationally expensive.

Comment: Thanks! So the easiest first step for me here will be to try to materialize the RL with SQWRL first with the initial assumption that all the SQWRL reasoning only works in RL mode; then run the DL reasoner on top of that and hope that it works for my ontology. The full solution is to add SQWRL support to the compatible DL reasoner which will be the next step.